# Portable SVNServer for windows

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn-server, usb-drive

I want to be able to store my projects in a usb stick, under svn control.
is there a way of doing it?
I don't need any windows authentication, the svn suits me fine.
I've read that visualSVN server can become portable, by creating a .bat file that calls all the necessary to run the process.
Does anyone knows anything about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most, probably all SVN clients support the `file://` protocol, which lets you use a repository directly without the need to go through any server.

If the repository is on the flash drive, any security provided by the server is worthless.  SVN security only applies to remote repository access.

Comment: So, I'd just need a rapidSVN or a tortoise?

Comment: Now I just feel really dull... thanks a million, mate. those are very informal projects, there's no need to have any security at all

Comment: So, would this be similar to the distributed repositories of GIT?